# CORBA differentiate servant behavior on the ip of server (incomming request)

Tags: java, interface, corba

I would like to create CORBA server application with 1 or many servants (for example HelloWorld).
Server will be run on machine with many ipaddresses. 
For example I got only 1 method in the object HelloWorld -> sayHello().

However I would like to return different results (for example Hello in different language) based on the ip reached by the client.

example:
SERVER1 with two ips: IP 1.1.1.1, IP 2.2.2.2.

- client invokes method on ip 1.1.1.1 should get response "Hello".
- client invokes method on ip 2.2.2.2 should get response "Hi".

How to promote interface ip to HelloWorld sayHello() method that I could response relevant?

I do not have possiblity to change client implementation. My goal is to simulate a lot of the CORBA servers on a single machine. Of course all CORBA servers have different state (different helloworld answer). Is it possible? How?

Please help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no portable way to know that, that I am aware of. Remember that CORBA tries very hard to hide the transport from the application, and CORBA can run over a variety of transports, not just TCP/IP. The ORB in your server is going to be listening on those 2 IP address and send client requests into the POA. I don't think the IP address is propagated that far. If there is any support for that at all it would be specific to your ORB.